# Why is this code not multithreaded (trying to read a file with pandas read_csv in chunks and process each chunk in a separate thread)

Tags: python, pandas, python-multithreading

As my title, and this is part of the code:

```
def read_chunk(_chunk):
    return str(_chunk.dtypes[0])


def read_file_in_chunks(_input_file_path, _col_index):
    _dtypes = []
    _df_chunked = pd.read_csv(_input_file_path,
                              na_values=[".", "NA"],
                              chunksize=10000,
                              encoding="latin1",
                              low_memory=False,
                              sep="\t",
                              usecols=[_col_index])
    _processes = []

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
        _processes = executor.map(read_chunk, _df_chunked)

        for _process in _processes:
            _dtypes.append(_process)

    return _dtypes
```

So, basically, I want to check the dtype (for all rows in a column) for each column in a very large text-file. I do that by processing each column in chunks.

Comment: How have you determined that your code is not multithreaded?

Comment: Using htop in Linux, it shows only 1 thread using 100%.

Comment: Are you confident that `_df_chunked` is returning more than 1 item?

Comment: Python cannot use more than one *thread* at the time. That's called the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). If you expect multiple threads to run concurrently, you need to call compiled code that can release the GIL, some pandas functions do that (numpy as well). But just getting the `len` of a DataFrame or converting it's dtype to str very  likely won't .

Comment: In this example, all your CPU power will be spend actually parsing the CSV file, and that happens in a single thread.